# Update $scope when contenteditable Elements Change with Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, contenteditable

I am new to Angular.js and have tried to follow several tutorials to learn how to two-way bind `contenteditable` elements in an `ng-repeat`.

I am using a shared 'store' between controllers, e.g.

```
  pushupsApp.factory('grids', function () {
    return [
      ...
      {
        'id': 1409875200000, // 2014-09-05
        'sets': [
          5,
          10,
          15,
          20,
          25,
          30
        ]
      },
      {
        'id': 1409912060233, // 2014-09-05 11:14
        'sets': [
          5,
          10,
          15,
          20,
          25,
          30
        ]
      }
    ];
  });

  pushupsApp.controller('indexController', function ($scope, grids) {
    $scope.grids = grids;
  });
```

This seems to work very well; if I change `$scope.grids` in one controller, that change is persistent in all others, until I refresh the page, of course.

Following [this](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/common-user-interface-patterns/editing-text-in-place-using-html5-content-editable.html) tutorial and the examples in the [Angular.js docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), I have the following controller and directive:

```
  pushupsApp.controller('gridController',
    function ($scope, $routeParams, $filter, grids) {
      var now = new Date(Date.now());

      $scope.date = $filter('date')(now, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
      $scope.grids = $filter('filter')(grids, {'id':$scope.date},
        function (actual, expected) {
          return angular.equals($filter('date')(actual, 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
            $filter('date')(expected, 'yyyy-MM-dd'));
        });
  }).directive('contenteditable', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function (scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {
        ngModel.$render = function () {
          element.html(ngModel.$viewValue || '');
        };

        element.bind('keyup', function () {
          scope.$apply(function () {
            ngModel.$setViewValue(element.html);
          });
        });
        }
      };
    });
```

## The Problem

My intention is that when I edit the `contenteditable` elements in an `ng-repeat`, `$scope.grids` updates too, mirroring the edit, upon the `keyup` event firing.

`$scope.grids` isn't updating though. I've tried to research what might be happening myself but as I am so new to Angular.js, I honestly don't know what I should be looking for! Everything I have found suggests that my current code should work.

For completeness, I have the following template too:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="grid.html">
  <p>{{date}}</p>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="grid in grids">
      <p ng-if="grids.length > 1">{{grid.id | date:'shortTime'}}</p>
      <ul>
        <li contenteditable="" ng-model="grids" ng-repeat="set in grid.sets">
          {{set}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</script>
```

Eventually, my 'store' will be persistent, but for now I am happy for it to only be per-session.

Any help would be much appreciated, and any other pointers too, about my Angular.js code in general and what the problem may be!

Thank you for your help! Jon

## This Might Help?!

I have noticed that when I change the `ng-model` attribute in my template to `grid.sets`, when the `keyup` event fires `$scope.grids` updates. *However*, the entire list of sets gets removed from the DOM and `$scope.grids`. Something might be happening here which may help solve the problem; Here's hoping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following my discovery (see **This Might Help**) I suddenly got very close to the solution!

As an entire chunk of data was being removed from `$scope.grids` I now knew I could narrow that chunk down to the `contenteditable` element and corresponding chunk of data in the 'store'.

Changing the `ng-template` attribute to `grid.sets[$index]` did just that.

It turns out the element was being removed from the DOM because I was missing parenthesis here:

```
          scope.$apply(function () {
            // ngModel.$setViewValue(element.html);
            ngModel.$setViewValue(element.html());
          });
```

That was just carelessness. The `contenteditable` element was losing `focus` after each round-trip so I changed the event to fire on `blur` instead.

## Problem, solved :-)

I hope this has helped, Jon